# CSS: Absolute Position Issue

Tags: css, position, absolute

In fact I am much familiar with HTML and CSS but when it comes to setup multiple hierarchical div with relative and absolute position giving me damn trouble.

What I have is below

```
<div id="firstdiv">

   <div id="secdiv">

      <div id="thirddiv">

         <div id="forthdiv">

         </div>

      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Now I want to align most div on absolute position so I set position relative to #firstdiv now set position absolute to #secdiv and all is going well

Now I want to set my #forthdiv absolute to #thirddiv and so I set #thirddiv to position relative and #forthdiv to position absolute and hear I am getting trouble.

#forthdiv is not considering parent (#thriddiv) relation but it is considering #firstdiv relation and  getting position according to #firstdiv.

Now how to set this all so absolute position div only consider its own parent and not root

Comment: post your CSS. It should work if you have thirddiv set to `position=relative`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/Mcp6L/

Comment: I already did this. Let me check other areas if affecting to it. I have spend whole morning to design this and when I am adding this to the site its taking now site parent div as a relative. Fufl.. let me check thanks and get back to you soon